# 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a login form with Django. I'm creating a view witch will handle both get and post requests for login.

Here how i designed it:

```
class Login(View):
    def get(self,request):
        c = {}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        return render_to_response("login.html", c)
    def post(self,request):
        username = request.get('username','')
        password = request.get('password','')
        user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if(user is not None):
            auth.login(request,user)
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I can get this form, but when i post i am getting:

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Error. What is the correct way to design such views?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use the `request.POST` dict-like object:

```
username = request.POST.get('username','')
password = request.POST.get('password','')
```

Answer (score 5):

you should use this for Get method otherwise Post for post method in python 3

```
  username = request.GET.get('username','')
  password = request.GET.get('password','')
```

Comment: Welcome, @Chirag Sukhwani. It doesn't seem to be relevant as there's an existing answer already. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28515508/11644167

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this same error because I had written a decorator like this:

```
from functools import wraps

def require_authenticated(view_function):
    @wraps
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return JsonResponse({"detail": "User is not authenticated"}, status=403)
        return view_function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

The problem here is the way of using the `functools.wraps` builtin (which returns a decorator), the fix is to pass the view function to it, like this:

```
from functools import wraps

def require_authenticated(view_function):
    @wraps(view_function)  # <- this is the fix!
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return JsonResponse({"detail": "User is not authenticated"}, status=403)
        return view_function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

Comment: Interesting.  Now doesn't it still require manual extraction of GET or POST or META and reconstruction of a JSON structure?

Answer (score 0):

```
**value1=int(request.GET['num1'])
value2=int(request.GET['num2'])**
```

just use GET if you are using python version 3.9

Answer (score 0):

If in case instead of putting your `views.py`'s function in `urls.py` i.e

```
path('<urlsname>', views.<view_function>)
```

But you have wrote `views.<form_class name>` then also this error comes

Answer (score -2):

I had encountered the same issue. Try writing 'GET' instead of 'get. Hope it solves.

```
username = request.GET('username','')
password = request.GET('password','')
```