# AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'status_code'

Tags: python, django

I got an error,AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'status_code'.I wrote test code,

```
def test_user(self):
    obj =     {
                "username": "tom",
                "email": "tom@gmail.com",
                "password": ""
    }

    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    response = factory.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/data/', obj)
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 400)
```

but when I run this code,the error happens.I followed this web site http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/ to write the test code,I think why this error happens.Of course,type of response is different from my ideal one,but what should I do?How can I fix this?

Comment: I was having a similar problem in my tests, due to my production code with a decorator using `functools.wraps` incorrectly, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58119138/149872

Answer (score 5):

`factory.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/data/', obj)` return `request` instance. You need to pass it to the view to test your view method:

```
request = factory.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/data/', obj)
response = your_view(request)
```

See example [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/).