# WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, html, django-views

I have the following codes:

models.py

```
class Job(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    associateddevice = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    associatedinterface = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    combinedparameters = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
```

forms.py

```
class JobForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ['associateddevice', 'associatedinterface','combinedparameters']
```

views.py

```
def device_port_selected(request, pk):
    
    devices = Device.objects.get(pk=pk)        
    tablename = 'dev_interface_'+str(pk)
    #print("tablename: " +tablename)
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT interface FROM {tablename} WHERE id >=2")
    righttable = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    #print(righttable)     
    if request.method == "POST":
        job = JobForm(request)        
        hostname = devices.hostname
        #print(device)
        
        try:
            selection=request.POST.get('portrange','')
        except:
            selection = ""       
        print(selection)     
        mode=request.POST.get('portmode','')        
        print(mode)        
        status=request.POST.get('portstatus','')
        print(status)
        portpara1 = request.POST.get('portpara1','')
        print(portpara1)
        portpara2 = request.POST.get('portpara2','')
        print(portpara2)
        #combined=mode + ";" +status + ";" + portpara1 + ";" + portpara2
        #print(combined)
        combined={'port_range':selection, 'port_mode':mode, 'port_status':status, 'port_param1':portpara1, 'port_param2': portpara2} 
        combinedfinal = {'device':hostname, 'configuration':combined}
        print(combinedfinal)
        job.combinedparameters=combinedfinal
        print(type(request.POST), '\n', request.POST)

    
        job.save()
       
        

        return redirect('/device/', {'device':Device.objects.all, 'devices':device})
        
    return render(request, 'interface/device_port_selected.html',{'devices':devices, 'righttable':righttable} )
```

All my request.POST.get are successful and there is data in each. When i press the save button, the `print(variable)` are printed correctly in my powershell. But I cant seem to save.
My web shows me the error of

`'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'`

I referred to the previous post by others: ['WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28515470/wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-get)
but the top 2 solution provided does not work. The first solution was adding `,''` behind the html name. So it becomes `request.POST.get('html name' , '')` . But this didnt change the output or solve the error. It still show the same error when i was using `request.POST.get('html name')`.
The 2nd solution was `request.GET.get` instead of `request.POST.get` but this give me the same error

Output of `print(type(request.POST), '\n', request.POST)`

```
<class 'django.http.request.QueryDict'>
 <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['ihYDX9Ug1ybl8aIKLI6kcaAjHvc7A6oIeUTadKbZcSJZURjGSWejiip7u9vJs7fQ'], 'portmode': ['Access'], 'port_param1': ['1\r\n1\r\n1'], 'portpara1': ['1\\n1\\n1'], 'portstatus': ['Enabled'], 'port_param2': ['1\r\n1\r\n1'], 'portpara2': ['1\\n1\\n1']}>
```

Here is the traceback from powershell:
[image]

Traceback in html:
[image: ![image|690x331](upload://mPLfkXRsNtSty4UzTBiyxwWSkhN.png)]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **request.POST.get('portmode','')** try using **request.headers('portmode')** or load your data into a dictionary as such **data = request.get_json()** and then access it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I used ```request.headers('portmode')``` and got the following error ```'HttpHeaders' object is not callable``` May I ask how to use ```data = request.get_json()```

Comment: Before doing that just **print(type(request.POST), '\n', request.POST)** to get an idea of what structure is being dealt with.

Comment: I just did the print statement. I have updated the post with the output

Comment: Using **.get** does not work? Make sure when sending data use **application/json**.

Comment: All the variable ```mode,status,portpara1,portpara2``` all is successful in getting the value from the textbox or textarea from the html. But when press the submit button is the page, it cannot save. I dont get it why

Comment: Okay, the issue is something else is **widgets.py** a 3rd party script or written from scratch? the command **return data.get(name)** is throwing the error, check the datatype of data, also the dictionary posted earlier has **no key 'name' in it**.

Comment: I managed to solved it. It was the issue of using django form. The main issue was ```job=JobForm(request)```, it is missing ```.POST``` behind ```request```. Followed by missing validation for the form, ```is_valid()```. I am not sure about the widgets.py part as I have never configured that part. This web was pass to me to continue programming. Thanks for your help anyway, I appreciate it a lot as I am still new to Django